# react-native-firebase and Proguard: can't find superclass or interface

Tags: android, proguard, react-native-firebase

I have a React Native app, and I am having trouble creating a Release build for Android. My issues started after adding react-native-firebase and the necessary Android Firebase dependencies.

I keep getting proguard errors even though I have specified `-keep class com.google.firebase.** { *; }` and `-keep class io.invertase.** { *; }`. For example I get a lot of compile errors such as `Warning: io.invertase.firebase.admob.RNFirebaseAdMobBanner$1: can't find superclass or interface com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener`. Please help.

Comment: Can you post some of your code?